# Using image as a background for NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there any way of using a jpeg/png image as a background for NSTextField?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1 solution:** You can simply do it like this:

```
NSImage *image = ...; //image for background
[_textfieldOutlet setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:image]];
```

Result:

[image: NSTextField with background]

---

**2 solution:** You can subclass Your `NSTextField` like this:

```
#import "TextFieldSubclass.h"

@implementation TextFieldSubclass

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self setDrawsBackground:NO];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    NSImage *image = ...; //image for background
    [image setFlipped:YES]; //image need to be flipped

    //use this if You need borders

    NSRect rectForBorders = NSMakeRect(2, 2, rect.size.width-4, rect.size.height-4);
    [image drawInRect:rectForBorders fromRect:rectForBorders operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];

    //if You don't need borders use this:

    //[image drawInRect:rect fromRect:rect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
}

@end
```

**Result with border:**

[image: with border]

**Result without border:**

[image: without border]